# Probability question --- sum, difference of two dice

Tags: probability

We drop casually two dice.We have the events :
a) The sum of two numbers is 10
b) The sum of two numbers is 7 and the difference of them is 3.
c)The sum of the numbers is at least 7 and the difference at most 3.
I have to find P(a),P(b) ,P(c) and $P(A\cup B)$

So my teacher solved this and he simply wrote :
P(a)  2 /21.

P(b)  Only 1/21

P(c)  2 /21

Then $P(A\cup B)$  is $2/21 \times 1/21= 2/441$

I Dont get any of these? can you explain the answers to me?

Comment: If we label the dice X and Y, there are 36 possible outcomes. For a), of these 36, 3 result in a sum of 10: X=4, Y=6; X=5, Y=5; X=6, Y=4. For b), one must be 5 and the other 2, so 2 of the 36 possibilities give us this. You can do c) similarly. Note that since a) and b) are mutually exclusive, the probability of their union is the sum of their probabilities (i.e. 5/36). This is with two standard 6-sided dice; perhaps you have a different situation?

Comment: You have done this considering overlapping right?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the outcomes of the dice as a set of pairs $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3),\ldots (6,6)$, all with the same probability of $\frac{1}{36}$ of occurring, then there are 3 ways to get a sum of 10: $(4,6),(6,4),(5,5)$, so $P(A) = \frac{3}{36} = \frac{1}{12}$.

For $B$ there just the options $(5,2),(2,5)$ exist, so $P(B) = \frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{18}$.

Because $A$ and $B$ cannot occur together (they are mutually exclusive, also called disjoint) $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) =\frac{5}{36}$.

For $C$, you could just make a square with all options ($6 \times 6$) and count the ones with the right sums and differences. Divide that count by $36$ for the probability.